# Flaw in calling read with a timeout

Tags: c, unix, signals, system-calls

I'm a newbie to system programming and I came across this program.

```
#include "apue.h"
static void sig_alrm(int);
int main(void)
{  
     int n;
     char line[MAXLINE];
     if (signal(SIGALRM, sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
     err_sys("signal(SIGALRM) error");
     alarm(10);
     if ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, line, MAXLINE)) < 0)
         err_sys("read error");
     alarm(0);
     write(STDOUT_FILENO, line, n);
     exit(0);
}
static void sig_alrm(int signo)
{
        /* nothing to do, just return to interrupt the read */
}
```

This program is meant to provide a timeout for read() system call. If read() takes more than, say, 30 seconds, then a signal will be generated. Now,

Quoting from the text book (It lists 2 flaws in the program, one of which is)

> If system calls are automatically restarted, the read is not interrupted when the SIGALRM
>   signal handler returns. In this case, the timeout does nothing.

I couldn't grasp the meaning of this statement. Could someone explain this

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following considerations are valid for Linux <= 2.6.11, but I believe the concepts apply also for recent kernels.

If a process is blocked on a system call it is put on a waitqueue in the `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` or `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` state. In the former case, upon receiving a signal, the kernel puts it back in the `TASK_RUNNING` state, adds the process to the runqueue and adds the signal to the list of pending signals.

When the process is scheduled, it continues the execution of the system call. Since the syscall was not completed, the possible return codes are:

- `EINTR`
- `ERESTARTNOHAND`
- `ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK`
- `ERESTARTSYS`
- `ERESTARTNOINTR`

On the exit path from the system call, the pending signals are checked. In this case, your `SIG_ALRM` handler is called and immediately afterwards the kernel checks the return code of the system call. In general, the following cases may occur:

- Return code is `EINTR`: the user mode process is resumed and the return value of `read` will be exactly -EINTR
- Return code is `ERESTARTNOINTR`: the system call is reexecuted
- Return code is `ERESTARTSYS`: system call is reexecuted if SA_RESTART flag is set, otherwise -EINTR is returned to userspace.
- Return code is `ERESTARTNOHAND` or `ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK`: usermode process is resumed and -EINTR returned.

Reexecuting a system call means that the process EIP is decremented by 2 and it is therefore forced to execute again `int 0x80`.

In this specific case, if the process is blocked on a read syscall from STDIN and it receives `SIG_ALRM`, from `man 7 signal`, section **Interruption of System Calls and Library Functions by Signal Handlers**:

```
If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is
interrupted by a signal handler, then the call will be
automatically restarted after the signal handler returns 
if the SA_RESTART  flag  was used; otherwise the call will 
fail with the error EINTR.

* read(2),  readv(2),  write(2),  writev(2), and ioctl(2) 
calls on "slow" devices.  A "slow" device is one where the 
I/O call may block for an indefinite time, for example, a
terminal, pipe, or socket.  (A disk is not a slow device 
according to this definition.)  If an I/O call on a slow 
device has already transferred some data by the time 
it is interrupted by a signal handler, then the call 
will return a success status (normally, the number of bytes
transferred).
```

This is the behaviour of ERESTARTSYS return code, i.e. the syscall is reexecuted when a signal is caught only if SA_RESTART is set, otherwise
it would return EINTR (**if no data has been transferred yet**).

So the first statement from your book

```
If system calls are automatically restarted [...]
```

means

```
If, upon receiving a signal, SA_RESTART is set
```

If so, the system call is restarted, it will block again and the alarm won't have any effect.

**References:**

- Understanding the Linux Kernel 3rd Ed, Chapter 10 (System Calls), Chapter 11 (Signals)
- man 7 signal